# How can I handle packages that require different typescript versions?

Tags: typescript

I am using some packages that require typescript version ^2.4. (react, apollo-client)

Another package I need to use (@reactivex/rxjs) is written against typescript 2.2.

When I try to compile my project, I get a slew of typescript issues because of the invalid .ts files in the @reactivex/rxjs project:

```
[at-loader] ./node_modules/@reactivex/rxjs/src/Subscriber.ts:151:5
    TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'.

[at-loader] ./node_modules/@reactivex/rxjs/src/Subscriber.ts:145:5
    TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

...etc
```

One potential way around this seems to be to force typescript to not check the files in `node_modules`. However, adding `"exclude": ["node_modules"]` to my tsconfig.json does not solve this issue.

Comment: It's `"exclude"` not `"excludes"`

Comment: thanks - that was a typo in my question. 'exclude' does not work in tsconfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the only option is to disable `--strictNullChecks` for whole project. Because then you import `*.ts` files from your code it becomes part of your codebase too. Other option is to use `rxjs` in compiled version with `*.d.ts` files, but I'm not sure if `rxjs` supports such use case.